# Image is overflowing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am trying to design a movie watchlist but having problems maintaining the design. I am using tmbd api to fetch movie data. Now I want each setion to look like the first one (halo). But in the other two the image are overflowing and messing up the design. Please help

[image: My watch List]

**React Code Snippet**

```css
/* This is the corresponding style.scss */

@import "../../mixins.scss";
.watchList {
  background-color: var(--black);
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  .item {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 2px solid white;

    .itemWrapper {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;

      .posterBlock {
        position: relative;
        width: 40%;

        .posterImg {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      }

      .textBlock {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 15px;
        .title {
          font-size: 2em;
          color: white;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .info {
          .text {
            margin-right: 10px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            line-height: 24px;
            color: white;
            &.bold {
              font-weight: 600;
              opacity: 1;
            }
          }
        }

        .btn {
          background-image: linear-gradient(
            92.88deg,
            #455eb5 9.16%,
            #5643cc 43.89%,
            #673fd7 64.72%
          );
          color: white;
          font: var(--black);
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 500;
          height: 2rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          border-radius: 8px;
          border-style: none;
          margin-top: 10px;
          padding: 1.3rem;
        }
        .btn:hover {
          box-shadow: rgba(80, 63, 205, 0.5) 0 1px 30px;
          transition-duration: 0.1s;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
/* this is WatchList.jsx */

import dayjs from "dayjs";
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ContentWrapper from "../../components/contentWrapper/ContentWrapper";
import Img from "../../components/lazyLoadImage/Img";
import "./style.scss";
import { removeFromWatchList } from "../../store/homeSlice";

const WatchList = () => {
  const { url, watchList } = useSelector((state) => state.home);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const removeMovieFromWatchList = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
    dispatch(removeFromWatchList(item));
  };

  return (
    <div className="watchList">
      <ContentWrapper>
        {watchList.length > 0 &&
          watchList.map((m) => {
            const posterUrl = m[0].poster_path
              ? url.poster + m[0].poster_path
              : PosterFallback;
            return (
              <>
                <div className="item">
                  <div className="itemWrapper">
                    <div
                      className="posterBlock"
                      onClick={() => navigate(`/${m[2]}/${m[0].id}`)}
                    >
                      <Img className="posterImg" src={posterUrl} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="textBlock">
                      <span className="title">{m[0].title || m[0].name}</span>

                      <div className="info">
                        <span className="text bold">Released on:</span>
                        <span className="text">
                          {dayjs(m[0].release_date).format("MMM D, YYYY")}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="info">
                        <span className="text bold">Type:</span>
                        <span className="text">
                          {m[2] === "movie" ? "Movie" : "TV series"}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="info">
                        <span className="text bold">Added on: </span>
                        <span className="text">
                          {dayjs(m[1]).format("MMM D, YYYY")}
                        </span>
                      </div>

                      <button
                        className="btn"
                        onClick={() => removeMovieFromWatchList(m[0].id)}
                      >
                        Remove
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
      </ContentWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WatchList;
```

**Example Rendered Output**

```css
:root {
  --black: black;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.watchList {
     background-color: var(--black);
     padding-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item {
     margin: 10px auto;
     width: 500px;
     height: 350px;
     border: 2px solid white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock {
     position: relative;
     width: 40%;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock .posterImg {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .title {
     font-size: 2em;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text {
     margin-right: 10px;
     opacity: 0.5;
     line-height: 24px;
     color: white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text.bold {
     font-weight: 600;
     opacity: 1;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .btn {
     background-image: linear-gradient(92.88deg, #455eb5 9.16%, #5643cc 43.89%, #673fd7 64.72%);
     color: white;
     font: var(--black);
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 500;
     height: 2rem;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 8px;
     border-style: none;
     margin-top: 10px;
     padding: 1.3rem;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .btn:hover {
     box-shadow: rgba(80, 63, 205, 0.5) 0 1px 30px;
     transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="watchList">
  <div class="ContentWrapper">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://pad.mymovies.it/filmclub/2024/01/133/locandina.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Halo</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://www.tres-click.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dasperfektedinner.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Das perfekte Dinner</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZThiYTE5YTgtYzJhNy00ZTM2LTgyNTMtOTExZWNlZTBjZWYwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Watch What Happens Live with Andy Cohen</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set the width of the `.textblock`.

```css
.watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-left: 15px;
     width: 40%;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --black: black;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.watchList {
     background-color: var(--black);
     padding-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item {
     margin: 10px auto;
     width: 500px;
     height: 350px;
     border: 2px solid white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock {
     position: relative;
     width: 40%;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock .posterImg {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 40%;
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .title {
     font-size: 2em;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text {
     margin-right: 10px;
     opacity: 0.5;
     line-height: 24px;
     color: white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text.bold {
     font-weight: 600;
     opacity: 1;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .btn {
     background-image: linear-gradient(92.88deg, #455eb5 9.16%, #5643cc 43.89%, #673fd7 64.72%);
     color: white;
     font: var(--black);
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 500;
     height: 2rem;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 8px;
     border-style: none;
     margin-top: 10px;
     padding: 1.3rem;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .btn:hover {
     box-shadow: rgba(80, 63, 205, 0.5) 0 1px 30px;
     transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="watchList">
  <div class="ContentWrapper">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://pad.mymovies.it/filmclub/2024/01/133/locandina.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Halo</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://www.tres-click.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dasperfektedinner.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Das perfekte Dinner</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZThiYTE5YTgtYzJhNy00ZTM2LTgyNTMtOTExZWNlZTBjZWYwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Watch What Happens Live with Andy Cohen</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Width not working in Flexbox!

In your .posterBlock class, you use width and it not worked.
If you add these codes instead of width, it worked!

```
flex-basis: 200px;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

```css
:root {
  --black: black;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.watchList {
     background-color: var(--black);
     padding-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item {
     margin: 10px auto;
     width: 500px;
     height: 350px;
     border: 2px solid white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     align-items:center;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock {
     position: relative;
    flex-basis: 40%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .posterBlock .posterImg {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     flex:1;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .title {
     font-size: 2em;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text {
     margin-right: 10px;
     opacity: 0.5;
     line-height: 24px;
     color: white;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .info .text.bold {
     font-weight: 600;
     opacity: 1;
}
 .watchList .item .itemWrapper .textBlock .btn {
     background-image: linear-gradient(92.88deg, #455eb5 9.16%, #5643cc 43.89%, #673fd7 64.72%);
     color: white;
     font: var(--black);
     displ
```

```html
<div class="watchList">
  <div class="ContentWrapper">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://pad.mymovies.it/filmclub/2024/01/133/locandina.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Halo</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://www.tres-click.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dasperfektedinner.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Das perfekte Dinner</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="itemWrapper">
        <div class="posterBlock">
          <Img class="posterImg" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZThiYTE5YTgtYzJhNy00ZTM2LTgyNTMtOTExZWNlZTBjZWYwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="textBlock">
          <span class="title">Watch What Happens Live with Andy Cohen</span>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Released on:</span>
            <span class="text">Mar 17, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Type:</span>
            <span class="text">TV series</span>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <span class="text bold">Added on: </span>
            <span class="text">Mar 12, 2024</span>
          </div>
          <button class="btn">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```